# ggbiplot graphical display in groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, ggbiplot

I am learning biplot with `wine` data set. How does R know Barolo, Grignolino and Barbera are `wine.class` while we don't see the wine class column in the data set?

More details about the `wine` data set are in the following links

[ggbiplot - how not to use the feature vectors in the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195040/ggbiplot-how-not-to-use-the-feature-vectors-in-the-plot/27195584#27195584)

https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot

Thanks very much

Comment: You can see in the Environment that `wine.class` is a vector which is loaded when you call `data(wine)`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, `wine.class` does show as a vector. Would you elaborate more? I exported the data set to a csv file but no information of wine.class was visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `wine` dataset, you have 2 objects, one `data.frame` `wine` with 178 observations of 13 quantitative variables:

```
str(wine)
'data.frame':   178 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Alcohol       : num  14.2 13.2 13.2 14.4 13.2 ...
 $ MalicAcid     : num  1.71 1.78 2.36 1.95 2.59 1.76 1.87 2.15 1.64 1.35 ...
 $ Ash           : num  2.43 2.14 2.67 2.5 2.87 2.45 2.45 2.61 2.17 2.27 ...
 $ AlcAsh        : num  15.6 11.2 18.6 16.8 21 15.2 14.6 17.6 14 16 ...
 $ Mg            : int  127 100 101 113 118 112 96 121 97 98 ...
 $ Phenols       : num  2.8 2.65 2.8 3.85 2.8 3.27 2.5 2.6 2.8 2.98 ...
 $ Flav          : num  3.06 2.76 3.24 3.49 2.69 3.39 2.52 2.51 2.98 3.15 ...
 $ NonFlavPhenols: num  0.28 0.26 0.3 0.24 0.39 0.34 0.3 0.31 0.29 0.22 ...
 $ Proa          : num  2.29 1.28 2.81 2.18 1.82 1.97 1.98 1.25 1.98 1.85 ...
 $ Color         : num  5.64 4.38 5.68 7.8 4.32 6.75 5.25 5.05 5.2 7.22 ...
 $ Hue           : num  1.04 1.05 1.03 0.86 1.04 1.05 1.02 1.06 1.08 1.01 ...
 $ OD            : num  3.92 3.4 3.17 3.45 2.93 2.85 3.58 3.58 2.85 3.55 ...
 $ Proline       : int  1065 1050 1185 1480 735 1450 1290 1295 1045 1045 ...
```

There is also one `vector` `wine.class` that contains 178 observations of the qualitative `wine.class` variable:

```
str(wine.class)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "barolo","grignolino",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The 13 quantitative variables are used to compute the PCA:

```
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
```

while the `wine.class` variable is just used to color the points  on the plot

Comment: Thank you for your patience. So `wine` and `wine.class` have to be separated in order for the `pca` analysis to run. So in this following code, how does R know where to look for `wine.class` to put them together in the graph. `ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
  groups = wine.class, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = '') +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', legend.position = 'top')` When I load the data, I had to load `wine` only, not `wine.class`.

Comment: `wine.class` is loaded as well as `wine` `data.frame` when you do `data(wine)`. and it's `groups = wine.class` that makes the colors and elipses (try to remove it)

Comment: Oh I got it. So they are linked but not necessarily displayed in  one sheet. Thanks very much